# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down exception from DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, http, http-post, httpclient

I am doing a HttpPost with a DefaultHttpClient instance.and consuming it after getting response.

As follows. (It is a runtime exception)

```
httpResponse =  m_httpClient.execute(postRequest);
HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

if (entity != null) {
}
EntityUtils.consume(entity);
```

Still I am getting exception as,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down.
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.assertStillUp(SingleClientConnManager.java:175)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.getConnection(SingleClientConnManager.java:209)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$1.getConnection(SingleClientConnManager.java:190)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:391)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
        at com.pixalate.etl.adserver.appnexus.api.AppNexusApiManager.executeRequest(AppNexusApiManager.java:374)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Given that the exception is being thrown from the first line of your code snippet, it seems that you need to look at what's happened to `m_httpClient` before this code is executed.

Comment: Even when the above exception rises m_httpClient have value.I am tracking it value in logger.Also the exception is not occurring very soon i launch my application.If i am running that for a long time say a day,it will occur.After that continuously it will come.